# Android Gestures not working on Image

Tags: android, gestures

I am trying to get swipe gestures to work only on a simple image. Does anyone no why its not working. I get "`ontouchnow`" but no left or right displayed on the textview.

I have listed the code below :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GestureDetectorCompat gesyObject;
    private TextView textView2;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gesyObject = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GesyOne());

        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                textView2.setText("ontouchnow");
                return gesyObject.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });


    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.gesyObject.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    } */

    class GesyOne extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if (event2.getX() > event1.getX()) {
                textView2.setText("LEFT");

            } else if (event2.getX() < event1.getX()) {
                textView2.setText("RIGHT");
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  [Subsampling Scale Image View](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view)

Answer (score 0):

I got this working now. Needed to add onDown motion event return true. Sorted.